# Copying multiple files knowing their directories

Tags: linux

I have multiple files' directories and i need to copy them into specific folder using terminal, how do i do it. I also have access to GUI of the system, as all this is being done in virtual machine using ssh

Answer (score 0):

According to its manpage, `cp` is capable of copying various source files to one output directory.
The syntax is as follows:

```sh
cp /dir1/file1 /dir1/file2 /dir2/file1_2 /outputdir/
```

Using this command, you can copy files from multiple directories (`/dir1/` and `/dir2/` in this example) to **one** output directory (`/outputdir/`).